# Replicate nt:unstructured nodes in AEM

Tags: aem

I am storing a quite a lot of metadata in the JCR which is accessed via OSGi services from Sightly pages and when rendering adaptive forms. The metadata are all stored in a tree of nt:unstructured nodes on the publish instance.

Ideally I'd like to reverse-replicate these nodes to my author on a continuous basis, and then potentially use tree-activation to push from the author back to publish.

The problem is this: It seems that AEM's replication capability does NOT pick up nt:unstructured nodes. I assume this is by design, but I'd like to confirm.

Also, what would be an appropriate work-around? Should I change my nt:unstructured nodes to cq:Page nodes? That feels wrong.

Comment: You could try to introduce your own node type, similar to `cq:Page` or `cq:Component`. I am not aware of all the restrictions of the product's replication service, but checking out the service's configurations in Felix might be a good idea as well. Perhaps it is configurable what can be replicated an what not.

Comment: I've confirmed that the replication OSGi service does allow replication of nt:unstructured nodes, but unfortunately there are some further complications :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to close this out:

The com.day.cq.replication.Replicator package contains an OSGi component called Replicator.

By using this component, you can replicate nt:unstructured nodes as well with a call like:

```
replicator.replicate(session,ReplicationActionType.ACTIVATE, nodePath);
```